# VS 2012 New project creation throws exception

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

**this isn't duplicate question**

I am using windows 7 , vs 2102.

Whenever I try to `create a new project` I get this exception,

> set property 'system.windows.resourcedictionary.deferrablecontent'
>   threw an exception

have checked installed program list I don't have any Azure installed.

Also `devenv /resetuserdata` doesn't help , it shows  `Unknown error` .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not closing visual studio and trying to hit resetuserdata command.

OR there are multiple users logged in (someone might have disconnected and visual studio running) , nutshell only when visual studio is running unknown error will be visible, I tried and i too get unknown error. (though yours and mine unknown error may be different)

Reboot machines and try resetuserdata that should solve this error.

Comment: ahaa..yeah never tried closing vs , it didn't work this time. let me reboot once and try.. thanks for answer though..

Comment: I just logged off and tried resetuserdata, it is running atleast.. :) hope it will solve the problem